# Find distinct elements after nested splitting in Unix

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, split, unique

I have a string containing multiple values separated by a space.
Now each individual value have characters separated by another delimiter '-'.

I am looking for a nice solution using shell script to find unique strings in the first field of values

To clarify, my string is of the following format

`abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def`

Now i want to find the unique string in the first field of each individual strings.
So in this, "abc", "123" and "789" to an array.

Comment: Please clarify what is the expected output. count, unique substrings or both ?

Comment: This is a one-liner using `sed`, `sort`, and `uniq` utilities: `echo "$string" | sed 's/-[^ ]*\ \?/\n/g' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, this would work:

```
echo abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def | sed --expression='s/\ /\n/g' | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort | uniq
```

And if you want to get only the count, append wc -l to the end of that

```
echo abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def | sed --expression='s/\ /\n/g' | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: The sed part can be simplified as `sed 's/ /\n/g' file` or `tr ' ' $'\n' < file`

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` and assuming the string is in a `bash` variable:

```
perl -lane 'my %words; $words{(split(/-/, $_))[0]} = 1 for @F; print scalar(keys %words)' <<<"$thevariable"
```

If you want the unique values and not the total number of them, `print join(" ", keys %words)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it short:

```
tr ' ' $'\n' < file | awk -F- '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {print i}}'
```

Feeding an array as requested:

```
arr=( $(tr ' ' $'\n' < file | awk -F- '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {print i}}') )
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

```
abc
123
789
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -lnE '
    my %seen; $, = "\n";
    say grep { !$seen{$_}++ } map { (split /-/)[0] } split / /
' file
```

You can replace `file` by *here-string* :

```
<<< 'abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def'
```

## Output

```
abc
123
789
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using bash only.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## If the string is not in an array format, use the code below.
##: string='abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def'
##: string=${string// / $'\n'}
##: mapfile -t array <<< "$string"

array=(abc-def-ghi 123-456-789 abc-xyp-lmn 789-abc-def)

declare -A uniq

for i in  "${array[@]%%-*}"; do
  ((uniq["$i"]++))
done

printf '%s\n' "${!uniq[@]}"
```

Comment: Nice answer ;) .